# PHP socket_bind(): unable to bind address [10049]

Tags: php

I am using SocketServer.class.php in wamp and trying to connect real Ip 128. .. and port :8010 but process end with

> Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [10049]: The requested address is not valid in its context. in C:\wamp\www\tcpclient\SocketServer.class.php on line 55

with packet sender I can see response coming from each 1 second interval

any idea ??

Comment: did you open the port in firewall ?

Comment: SocketServer.class what is the port that you using there?

Comment: port is 8010 and it is open

Comment: Could please show us the code where you do the binding? And better providing `ifconfig` result, you can mask real IP with some XXXes.